# wp reset query not working in admin_notices

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin and I need to show admin notices about the posts. I called to the function which provides messages.

```
add_action('admin_notices', array($this, 'postNotices'));
```

And here is my function :

```
public function postNotices() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'demo_post_type',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
    $query_post = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query_post->have_posts()) {
        while ($query_post->have_posts()) {
            $query_post->the_post();
            // $my_meta = 'Im getting post meta here'; ?>
                <div>Some notification</div>
            <?php wp_reset_query();
        }
    }
}
```

Notices showing is working correctly but When I try to create a new post it appears last post data such as post title in the new post page.
It means `wp_reset_query()` function is not working with `admin_notices` hook I think. Has anyone a suggestion?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be calling `wp_reset_postdata()`, not `wp_reset_query()`, also, that call should be done outside your `while` loop, and not inside it.

Comment: No, I tried but it's useless. I found the answer and will post in answers. thank you @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard research I foud the answer,
Here we go,

```
     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'demo_post_type',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );

    $query_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($query_posts as $post) {
        ?>
         <div>Some notification</div>
        <?php
    }
```

No need to add functions like `wp_reset_query()`. Found the answer but don't know what the logic is. if anyone know, Please comment here.

Comment: It's always recommended that after a query you reset it using [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: is this compulsory? I'm not creating a post object in here.

Comment: Well you actually are. `get_posts()` uses `WP_Query` class to create query object ;) [Read more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Comment: Also please don't use `'posts_per_page' => -1,`, instead use something like `'posts_per_page' => 999`, depending on your post count. -1 means literally every single post, and if you have much of them, this makes your query slow. This is kind of an optimization :)

Comment: ah yeah. Thanks @dingo_d . *thumb up* ;)